# Showing that $\max\{f+g\} \leq \max f + \max g$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given real-valued continuous functions $f, g$, is the following (and why?) inequality true?

$$\max \{f + g \} \leq \max f + \max g$$

Can someone give me a proof? I suspect the min is the reverse inequality

Comment: $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and $f(x)\leq \max f$, and $g(x)\leq \max g$.

Comment: *Assuming the maxima* ***exist***, then yes, that is true. In general, you would have to use the supremum.

Comment: Oh so $\max(f + g)(x) \leq \max \max (f + g) \leq \max ( \max f + \max g ) = \max f + \max g$

Comment: @sizz That's an interesting way of looking at it.

Comment: Remark: Use the following result. If $f$ has domain $X$, and if $a$ is a real number, and if for all $x \in X$ it holds that $f(x)\leq a$, then $\max f \leq a$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suprema proof: prove $\sup(f+g) \le \sup f + \sup g$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207335/suprema-proof-prove-supfg-le-sup-f-sup-g)

Comment: @goblin, A counter example of the Remark: $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = 1 - e^{-x^2}$. $\sup f = 1$, but the maximum doesn't exist and $f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x$.

Comment: Basically, I'm curious about how to prove that $\mathrm{max} \{f + g\}$ exists under the existence of $\mathrm{max} f$ and $\mathrm{max} g$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For all $x$, $$f(x)\le \max f(x)$$ and $$g(x)\le\max g(x).$$ Now add the two together.

Answer (score 1):

let $\max g(z):=g(z^*)$, $\max f(z):=f(z^*)$ then $$f(z)\le f(z^*)$$ $$g(z)\le g(z^*) $$  then $$\forall z : (f+g)(z)=f(z)+g(z)\le f(z^*)+g(z^*)$$ $$\max(f+g)(z)\le f(z^*)+g(z^*)=\max f(z)+\max g(z)$$

Comment: the only way to replace max $g(x)$ by $g(x^*)$ is that g is continuous and the domain should be compact, for example if the domain is $\Bbb R$ and g=x you cant replace max g by $g(x^*)$, that is the max is not necessarily an image.

Answer (score 0):

More generally we have:$$\sup_{x\in A} ( f(x)+g(x))\le \sup_{x\in A} \left( f(x)+\sup_{y\in A} g(y)\right)=\sup_{x\in A} f(x)+\sup_{y\in A} g(y)$$