# Prove that $\sup_{x\in S}|f(x) + g(x)| \leq \sup_{x\in S}|f(x)|+ \sup_{x\in S}|g(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis

Let S be a set and $f,g: S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded functions. Prove that $\sup_{x\in S}|f(x) + g(x)| \leq \sup_{x\in S}|f(x)|+ \sup_{x\in S}|g(x)|$.

---

How exactly do I prove this? It seems kind of obvious but those are the type of problems I usually miss something on...

Since the range of $f,g$ is $\mathbb{R}$ we have that for all $x\in S$, $f(x),g(x)\in \mathbb{R}$. So obviously the triangle inequality would give us $$|f(x)+g(x)|\leq |f(x)|+|g(x)|.$$

I guess the next step is where I'm uncertain. Can I now claim that $\sup_{x\in S}|f(x) + g(x)| \leq \sup_{x\in S}|f(x)|+ \sup_{x\in S}|g(x)|$, just from what I have? Feels like something is amiss.

Comment: Make it two steps. You know $\lvert f(x)+g(x) \leqslant \lvert f(x)\rvert +\lvert g(x)\rvert$ by the triangle inequality. Now take the $\sup$ on the right hand side only, $\lvert f(x)+g(x)\rvert \leqslant \sup_{y\in S}\lvert f(y)\rvert + \sup_{z\in S} \lvert g(z)\rvert$. Now take the $\sup$ of the left hand side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suprema proof: prove $\sup(f+g) \le \sup f + \sup g$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207335/suprema-proof-prove-supfg-le-sup-f-sup-g)

Comment: What if the sup of the left side is not an element of the left side? Doesn't that leave open the possibility that the $\sup|f(x) + g(x)|$ could be greater than or equal to $\sup|f(x)| + \sup|g(x)|$?

Answer (score 1):

$\forall x \in S : |f(x) + g(x)| \le |f(x)| + |g(x)|$. Now let $s_f := \sup_{x \in S} |f(x)|$ and $s_g := \sup_{x \in S} |g(x)|$, then $\forall x \in S : |f(x) + g(x)| \le s_f + s_g$. Now take the supremum on the left to obtain the statement.