# Suprema proof: Prove $\sup(f+g)\leq \sup f+\sup g$

Tags: analysis

I need help with these:

1) Show the following inequality for the supremum of functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ 
$$
\sup(f+g)(x)\leq \sup f(x)+\sup g(x)
$$

2) What can you say about a set $M$ of real numbers if you know that $\sup M = \inf M$?

Could you please, before you just giving the proof write down the definitions you are using. I do not want the direct proof, only how I should think and what definitions I should use, so I can try to proof it by myself before I see your guys proof :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207335/suprema-proof-prove-supfg-le-sup-f-sup-g?rq=1).

Comment: Sorry.
What can you say about a set M if you know that sup M = inf M?

Show the following inequality for the supremum of functions f: R-> R and g: R->R: sup(f+g)(x)≤supf(x)+supg(x)

Comment: If you have details to add to your qeustion, please add them by editing your question and not commenting.

Comment: Did you by $M$ mean a set *of real numbers* or the set of all pink Afghan elephants in blue pyjamas somehow equipped with a total ordering?

Comment: What are your definitions of $\sup$ and $\inf$?

Comment: i did just copy paste the question. But i will change it to real numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1)

$\forall x\ f(x)\le\sup f$ ($\sup$ is upper bound)

$\forall x\ g(x)\le\sup g$ (idem)

$\forall x\ f(x)+g(x) ≤ \sup f+\sup g$ (add inequalities)

$\sup f+g ≤ \sup f+\sup g$ (because $\sup$ is the least upper bound)

(2) Your "amount" is "set"?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. yes, I meant set.

Comment: Find an example to show that a strict inequality that may occur.

I took 4sin(x) as f and 3cosx as g. Is this correct?

f(x)+g(x)=5sin(x+y) has sup(f+g)(x)=5 which is strict inequality with supf+supg = 7.