# Real Analysis - Inequality of Supremum in functions

Tags: real-analysis

If |f(x)−g(x)| < ε for all x∈A, then  Sup(of A)F−sup(of A)G ≤ ε.

I am trying to prove this statement. And I tried to implement a similar idea as Suprema Proof. ([Suprema proof: prove $\sup(f+g) \le \sup f + \sup g$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207335/suprema-proof-prove-supfg-le-sup-f-sup-g))

However, the idea that Supremum need not necessarily be in contained in the domain gives a little more room in the second part. (strict inequality turns into less than or equal to). I need a little hint on how to tweak with this idea of supremum.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x) <g(x)+\epsilon$ for all $x \in A$. This implies that $f(x) <\sup_{y \in A} g(y)+\epsilon$. This in turn means that $\sup_{y \in A} g(y)+\epsilon$ is an upper bound for $\{f(x): x\in A\}$. Hence $\sup_{y \in A} f(y) \leq \sup_{y \in A} g(y)+\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I definitely understood the idea. Can I assume f(x) > g(x) without loss of generality here.

Comment: @Joon No need to assume that $f(x)>g(x)$. If $|a| <\epsilon$ then $a <\epsilon $ whether $a$ is positive or not. [$a=f(x)-g(x)$ in our case].