# Prove that $\sup \{f(x)+g(x):\space x\in X\}\leq \sup \{f(x):\space x\in X\}+\sup \{g(x):\space x\in X\}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> ***I know that this question had been answered before*** [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207335/prove-supfg-le-sup-f-sup-g) but I am asking to please check a method used by me which resulted in the wrong conclusion.

Let $X$ be a nonempty set, let $f$ and $g$ be defined on $X$ and have bounded range in $\mathbb R$.

Prove that $\sup \{f(x)+g(x):\space x\in X\}\leq \sup \{f(x):\space x\in X\}+\sup \{g(x):\space x\in X\}$

***My approach***:

Let $u=\sup \{f(x):\space x\in X\}$ and $v=\sup \{g(x):\space x\in X\}$

$$u\geq f(x)\space\forall\space x\in X$$

$$v\geq g(x)\space\forall\space x\in X$$

$$\therefore u+v\geq f(x)+g(x)\space\forall\space x\in X$$

Thus we can imply that $u+v$ is an upper bound of $f(x)+g(x)$

Let $w$ be another upper bound for $f(x)+g(x)$

$$\therefore w>f(x)+g(x)\space \forall \space x\in X$$

$$w-g(x)>f(x)\space \forall \space x\in X$$

$\therefore w-g(x)$ is an upper bound for $\{f(x):\space x\in X\}$

$$\therefore w-g(x)>u\space \forall \space x\in X$$
$$w-u>g(x)\space \forall \space x\in X$$

Thus we can imply that $w-u$ is an upper bound for $\{g(x):\space x\in X\}$
$$\therefore w-u>v\Rightarrow w>u+v$$
Now since $w$ is arbitrary, we can imply that any upper bound for $\{f(x)+g(x):\space x\in X\}$ would be greater than $u+v$

Thus we can imply that $u+v=\sup \{f(x)+g(x):\space x\in X\}$

$\therefore \sup \{f(x)+g(x):\space x\in X\}=\sup \{f(x):\space x\in X\}+\sup \{g(x):\space x\in X\}$ which clearly is not correct.

***I know that all this effort was irrelevant and unnecessary for this question but please help me find the mistake in this solution***

**THANKS**

Comment: You have to distinguish between strict inequalities and loose inequalities. Your proof is wrong because you have written $>$ instead of $ \geq $ at several places.

Comment: A quick tip on writing: If $A$ implies $B$, that means that if $A$ is true we can *deduce* or *infer* $B$. "We imply $B$" isn't quite correct.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen, Thanks, I'll try to remember it from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you already know that the proof was complete once you reached $u+v$ is an upper bound of $\{f(x)+g(x):x \in X\}.$

The problem in your attempt to prove the converse is concluding $w -g(x)$ is an upper bound for $\{f(x):x \in X\}.$ For a fixed $x,$ you have $w-g(x)\geq f(x)$ but you may not have $w-g(x)\geq f(y)$ for some $y \neq x.$ Therefore you cannot say $w-g(x)$ is an upper bound of $\{f(y):y \in X\}$.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now.